# Load view from storyboard UIViewController to external display

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, storyboard

I have 2 UIViewController in my storyboard, the first (Local View Controller) shows in my ipad Window. And there’s a second also in storyboard (External View Controller)

I want to send the view and its content of the second UIViewController (External View Controller) to another window that I have created to sent to external display.

I can create and send a UIwindow to the external display (UIScreen = 1) and I can add a view to it, and then add things like labels to it just fine. (They show on second display)

But if I want to send the UIviewcontroller “View” (with all its content) to the Windows I created for the external display… and I don’t see it.

Can I do this?

Look at the code bellow:

```
//this code is at my main view controller

#import "ASHExternalViewController.h" //for External View Controller

if ([[UIScreen screens] count] > 1)
    {
        // Associate the window with the second screen.
        // The main screen is always at index 0.
        UIScreen*    secondScreen = [[UIScreen screens] objectAtIndex:1];
        CGRect        screenBounds = secondScreen.bounds;

        //Alloc external window
 UIWindow *externalWindow = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:screenBounds];
        externalWindow.screen = secondScreen;

        // Add a white background View to the window
        UIView*            whiteField = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:screenBounds];
        whiteField.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

        [externalWindow addSubview:whiteField];


//up to this point all OK, I can see the white background view in the external display

        //
        //Add uiviewcontoller at storyborad to external window 
ASHExternalViewController *_externalView = [[ASHExternalViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ASHExternalViewController" bundle:nil];



        [whiteField addSubview: externalView.view];


//does no add the view in the external UIViewController in story board

        // Go ahead and show the window.
        externalWindow.hidden = NO;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

That's not the correct way to add a viewController's view hierarchy to a window.

In iOS 4 and above you should set it as the `rootViewController`

```
externalWindow.rootViewController = externalViewController;
```

It's also probably worth noting that you are not actually loading the viewController from a storyboard.

Comment: Thanks for you feedback, but that was not the solution. I used '[whiteField addSubview: externalView.view];' but before that I had tu call 'UIStoryboard *storyboard = self.storyboard;
        svc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"myExternalUIViewControllerID"];'

Comment: That's what the last line in my answer was referring to. Also it still stands that this is not the correct way to add a viewController's hierarchy to a window